# Добавить if чтоб все не сломалось)

Tags: javascript, jquery, функции, resize

Как добавить условие `if`, чтобы ничего не сломалось, или по другому решить эту задачу?

В общем, есть код:

```
function resizeHeight() {
    var height_wrap = $('#wrap_fixed').height() + 39;
    var result = $('.page .chord_text pre').css("min-height", height_wrap);
};

resizeHeight();

$(window).resize(function() {
    resizeHeight();
});
```

Нужно, чтобы он работал только с шириной окна больше `992px`. И при изменение ширины окна `(resize)` срабатывал снова.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вопрос. Не совсем понятно, что Вы хотите сделать.

Comment: Нужно чтобы он(код который я написал) работал только с ширины окна выше 992px. И при изменение ширины окна (resize) срабатывал снова.

Comment: Т.е. Вы не можете добавить if-условие с проверкой ширины окна браузера?

Answer (score -1):

```
function resizeHeight() {
    var height_wrap = $('#wrap_fixed').height() + 39;
    var result = $('.page .chord_text pre').css("min-height", height_wrap);
    if ($(window).width() < 960){
        result = $('.page .chord_text pre').css("min-height", "auto");
    }
};
resizeHeight();
$(window).resize(function() {
    resizeHeight();
});
```

Comment: Спасибо! Пожалуйста, не могли бы вы добавить пояснение, как именно решили и почему надо решать именно так?

Comment: На самом деле у мене нет глубоких познаний в JavaScript, я только начинаю его изучать, по этому не могу сказать что мое решение самое правильное. Мне сейчас главное чтоб работало.